# I get a request Timeout by upload big Data

Tags: timeout

I become sometimes a Request Timeout when i Upload big Data  >= 1 GB.
Smaller Data are no Problem.

Why might that be?
I set the Timeout to 0

Comment: What language, framework, code, anything?

Comment: PHP Jquery, these Request Timeout comes by all Upload Script, Its over 1 GB http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/